# How to Make Contact Form in VB .Net App?

Tags: vb.net, contact-form, ticket-system

I would like to integrate a ticket or support into my VB .NET app but I dont know how to do it properly. I would like that when someone opens the support ticket they can send like a regular email to my email.

I just need help with how to send email from the app to my email address.

Is this possible, and how would you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the [`System.NET.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace. The sending will be done via the [`SMTPClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class built into the .NET Framework.

You'll have to use a mail server like GMail I'm guessing, unless they have their own SMTP server (but you probably won't want the hassle of setting up and storing details for different clients' servers).

There's a good example of this here, which includes VB.NET and C# examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20546/How-to-Send-Mails-from-your-GMAIL-Account-through

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer , if i use gmail smtp , can multiple users use it to send me support tickets from diferent countries . I mean it wont be locked out or anything due to different IP ?

Comment: Multiple users should be fine, but GMail has some restrictions though - they would only let you send 500 messages per day ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hosted-setup/QzKX4ZcouHU)). You would also have to bear in mind that if someone decompiled your application, that someone could then have access to the GMail account that you have set up for sending yourself these emails; but this danger is present with nearly any application where you have to store some kind of login details.

Comment: Thanks for awesome answers , i will try to set it up , can i set it to automatically answer on email with like "thanks, we have your ticket"